# ZIO: How to dynamic inject a dependency

Tags: scala, zio

In *ZIO* we provide the Environment with initiating *Traits*:

```
program.provide(
  new Console.Live with MyComponent {}
)
```

What I wanted to do is to inject `MyComponent` dynamically from a configuration file - analog *Guice* Modules.

The whole scenario is described in this [Blog](https://medium.com/@pascal.mengelt/how-to-dynamically-inject-the-implementation-for-zio-with-macwire-bb51d4827966).

I can inject a dependency and then create the Environment like:

```
program.provide(
    new Console.Live with Components.Live {
      def compsService: Components.Service[Console] = service
    }
  )
```

Where `service` is injected.

This works but has one big disadvantage: We have to define the environment for all Service implementations. So for example if one of them wants to use `Random`, it is not possible, as we only provide `Console`.

Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: What does it have to do with ZIO?

Answer (score 1):

As an idea to solve this problem you could check this concept. Maybe sometimes i'll write library but i feel like it's enough to get idea.
https://gist.github.com/holinov/50fbf349fcb9f6e6c2b89ce319c20bba

If you could wrap injector creation in `RIO[Config, Injector]` and  injection in `RIO[Injector, Service]` it could fit your needs